# Categories as a generalisation of multifunctions

Tags: reference-request, category-theory

Categories, in some way, can be seen as a study of abstract functions. Is there a similar concept to categories in which we study abstract multifunctions?

Comment: Still [categories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_of_relations). Category theory does not *only* generalize the study of functions.

Comment: @StefanPerko Right, but for example, allegories generalise the study of relations. I was wondering if there was something specifically done for multifunctions, in particular understanding multifunctions as functions from a set to the positive powerset of another set (i.e. excluding the non-result possibility).

Comment: From your particular example, in your comment, I wonder have you looked at power allegories? They're a bit of a generalisation of a topos.